# Question on how these derivatives were obtained.

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

So I'm looking at [this](https://planetmath.org/DerivationOfTheLaplacianFromRectangularToSphericalCoordinates) website and I'm just wondering how the derivatives in the equations labeled as 7 were obtained.

Specifically the, $r_x, r_y, r_z, \theta_x, \theta_y, \theta_z, \phi_x, \phi_y$

The website said "The next step is to convert the right-hand side of each of the above three equations so that it only has partial derivatives in terms of
r
,
θ
and
ϕ
. We can do this by substituting the following values (which are easily derived from (2)) in their respective places in the above three equations" but I don't quite understand what the actual process was.

Answer (score 1):

I'll just discuss one as an example; the others are similar in nature. Specifically, I'll look at

$$\newcommand{\pdv}[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}
\pdv r x$$

As given in $(2)$ in the article, we have

$$r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$$

so

$$\pdv r x = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}$$

However, the end goal is to express things in terms of $r,\theta,\varphi$ since we want to contend with spherical coordinates. Well, we know that, aside from the relation for $r$, we have

$$x = r \sin \theta \cos \varphi$$

so

$$\pdv r x = \frac{r \sin \theta \cos \varphi}{r} = \sin \theta \cos \varphi$$

The others you are concerned about follow in a similar spirit: find the partial derivative in Cartesian coordinates, and use the spherical-Cartesian conversion formulas in $(2)$ to express that in terms of $r,\theta,\varphi$.

Comment: Thank you for this! Apparently my work was correct the entire time lol. I got them all but not in terms of $\theta,\phi$ so I started overthinking when I saw the website.